# How to make my methods work properly in this specific case?

Tags: c#, methods

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int nb1, nb2, AddEvens;
    Console.WriteLine("Que vaut le premier chiffre: ");
    nb1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Que vaut le deuxième chiffre: ");
    nb2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    AddEvens = Add(nb1, nb2);
    Console.WriteLine(AddEvens);
}

static int Add(int nb1, int nb2)
{
    for (int i = nb1; i < nb2; nb1++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        if (nb1 % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
            return sum;
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

---

I am trying to create a program that can sum up even numbers when they are detected. The first two `Console.Readline` s ask the user for the range in which it will add up the numbers together.

---

Here are my errors:

> 'Program.Add(int, int)': not all code paths return a value

and

> Unreachable code detected

The first one is at the start of the method creation the other is the `nb1++` in the `for` loop.

Comment: If (nb1 >= nb2), the loop is never executed. In this path of execution, as per your code, there is no return value. This is what the compiler complains about. You need to return a default value or raise an exception for this scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably want this:

```
static int Add(int nb1, int nb2)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = nb1; i < nb2; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Note: This follows the code from your example, and as such nb1 is included in the range, but nb2 is not. e.g. if nb1 is 4 and nb2 is 8, then the sum will return 10.

This method also makes the assumption that nb1 <= nb2.
If this is not always the case you might want to add the following code where you call the Add method:

```
if (nb1 <= nb2)
    AddEvens = Add(nb1,nb2);
else
    AddEvens = Add(nb2,nb1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must make sure that `nb1` is less than `nb2`, otherwise you must swap them. Then check whether `nb1` is odd, which requires you to increase it by 1. Finally make your `for` loop step 2 to catch only even numbers and add it to `sum`.
**Note 1:** `sum` must be defined and initialized outside `for` loop.
**Note 2:** I used `<=` as I think you want to include `nb2` if it is an even number, otherwise you should use `<`.

```
static int Add(int nb1, int nb2)
{
    int i, sum = 0;
    if (nb2 < nb1)
    {
        i = nb1;
        nb1 = nb2;
        nb2 = i;
    }
    if (nb1 % 2 != 0)
        nb1++;
    for (i = nb1; i <= nb2; i += 2)
        sum += i;
}
```

Comment: This won't work for negative numbers. -5 % 2 = -1, not 1. You would need to change it to be `if (nb1 % 2 != 0)`.

Comment: @RossGurbutt Thank you for reminding me. I corrected it.

Comment: I re-read my comment and found it non-welcoming. I don't like how resulting code looks like but it is not a reason to comment or vote. Sorry for disruption.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues you need to sort out in the method given.

**Compiler Error**
If you observe the execution when nb1 >= nb2,the loop is never executed and as per the code, there is no return value. This is what the compiler complains about. You need to include a default value when this happens.

**Other Errors**
If you observe/step through the for loop and return statement, you would realize the method would always return nb1.This is because you are returning in the first cycle of execution of loop and never waits the entire loop to be executed. Within the first execution, you would check if the number is an even number, if yes, you would return sum (which is 0+number) and if it is an odd number you would return the number itself.

What you probably need is to calculate the sum within the loop and return the result outside it.

Even this change would not fix the issue as the loop would not exit due the the increment statement nb1++. You are increment nb1 and the loop condition i < nb2 would be never reached.

```
 static int Add(int nb1, int nb2)
    {

        for (int i = nb1; i < nb2; nb1++) // Loop Condition would never be reached
        {
            int sum = 0;
            if (nb1 % 2 == 0)
            {
                sum = sum + i;
                return sum; // Returns before the entire loop is executed
            }
            return i; // Returns before the entire loop is executed
        }

       // No execution path when nb1>=nb2
    }
```

What you would need is

```
static int Add(int nb1, int nb2)
{
        int max = Math.Max(nb1,nb2);
        int min = Math.Min(nb1,nb2);
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = min; i < max; i++) // Change here
        {

            if (i % 2 == 0) // Change here
            {
                sum = sum + i;

            }
        }
        return sum; // Change here
}
```